# tcl regular expression, attempting to pull out a string between two patterns

Tags: regex, tcl

Gretings!
I am trying to use tcl regular expressions to strip off unwanted characters and keep the desired string.

The 4 basic string types are

```
I34/pAVDD_3
I32/pDVDD_15_2
I999/pAGND
I3/pDOUT_LG0
```

What I want to capture is what's in-between the p and the end of the string or the last underscore & number if it exists.  With the strings above I want to capture AVDD, DVDD_15, AGND, and DOUT_LG0.

I thought I had it with `[p](\w*)?[_][\d*]` but it doesn't work with I3/pDOUT_LG0 and after quite awhile of trying different things, I can't find a pattern that will work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
regexp {p(?:(\w+)_\d|(\w+))$} $str -> c1 c2
set result $c1$c2
```

One or the other will be empty, so the result is a simple concatenation of them.

Another possible solution is to strip off the unwanted parts:

```
regsub -all {.+p|_\d$} $str {}
```

Documentation:
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)